# I have got a stack of 2D images and I would like to convert it into a one 3D image

Tags: c++, image, opengl, 3d, 2d

I need to display a 3D image in my C++ application. I have got a few 2D cut images of an object taken from the same point.

Is there a library that can help me for example create a model from 8 images? Actually I'm using OpenGL but I am not sure it will be enough.

I know, there are programs that can do it as well, for example insight3d or GPU Gems. But i wanted to do it in my own C++ app. (Or maybe Java would be better?)

Here are some examples of 2D pictures I'm working with.

Below 3D cut in OpenGL. I found boundaries of regions in pictures(edge detection), put the coordinates in Vector (X and Y), and then draw GL_points for each pictures on different Z axis. I created a skeleton of image, but it is not a 3d object.

[image]

Comment: Hi Thamiar,

You would need to turn the points into a mesh, which will take a bit of logic/maths, otherwise you will have a constellation of individual points, which sounds like what you are experiencing.

Comment: It occurs to me you could also try voxel based rendering though the output would be quite different.  I will research and get back to you soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Thamiar after thinking about it a bit more I would probably go with the marching cubes algorithm to display slices as 3d, you could try looking at this **[Marching cubes algorithm tutorial](http://cns-alumni.bu.edu/~lavanya/Graphics/cs580/p5/web-page/p5.html)**, which is quite concise and reasonably well documented, with pictures which seem to show a similarity to what you are looking for.  There is also another site **[here](http://www.angelfire.com/linux/myp/MC/)** which is quite informative and also has some source for you to look at.

Let me know if I can help any further though and I shall try.

Comment: Thank you very much for responses!

GMasucci, I'll take a look on documents you send me. I still wish I could make it using OpenGl. I also found a short tutorial using that Lib 
http://www.icare3d.org/codes-and-projects/codes/opengl_geometry_shader_marching_cubes.html

I'll try to understand it, but for sure i will have other questions.

Comment: I will try and help out then:)

Comment: the icare3d.org link looks really good too, will read through that. The code looks good too

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell if your problem is for a game or just to view the images in 3D.  If it is just to view the images VTK has Java and C++ extensions.  VTK has a learning curve, but is a powerful 3D rendering tool for medical and volume imaging.  It works well with Qt, so you can build a nice GUI easily.

ImageJ also has some Java extensions for 3D viewing.

Both are free and offer complete source code if you want to delve into the inner workings.

Attached is a stack of MicroCT PNG images that I rendered in 3D using VTK.

Good luck!

[image]

Comment: Austin, VTK lib looks very promising, but i just cannot install it! I was using this tutorial: http://www.cs.uakron.edu/~xiao/visualization/VTK-Installation-Tutorial.html 
and I finally installed version 6. Unfortunatelly almost all tutorials are for 5.10 or below.
I tried to install 5.10 but in CMake appears line 
VTK_LARGE_DATA_ROOT and I do not have any idea what to do with it! On the website http://www.vtk.org/VTK/resources/software.html I can download only VTK_DATA_ROOT ( vtkdata-5.10.1.zip )
From where did you download Large one?

Comment: Hi Thamiar, I compiled VTK using x64 Visual Studio 2010 using CMake because my datasets are > 4GB when processed.  This website has pretty good directions on how to compile VTK: http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~cwyman/classes/common/howto/winVTK.html.  If you are using x86, there are some pre-compiled binaries on the web.

Comment: I see. This tutorial is similar to that, I used, but also do not solve my problem. I know that in  "VTK_DATA_ROOT" I have to put VTKData that i downloaded from VTK webpage, but what with  "VTK_LARGE _DATA_ROOT"?

Comment: I once again read all tutorials, and finally installed it succesfully. Than you Austin very much!